# PHP shell_exec permission denied read

Tags: php, linux, apache

These are my system specs and packages:

-Linux SERVERLOCAL 5.4.17-2136.321.4.el8uek.x86_64 #2
-PHP 8.0.27
-Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (Oracle Linux)
-Oracle Linux 8.0

I have the following code that is what I execute on the server:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE>cmd</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
        <label for="name">cmd:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cmd" name="cmd" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Executa"><br>
</form>

<HR>


<?php
$cmd = $_POST["cmd"];
echo "Answer: $cmd<br><br>";
$salida = shell_exec($cmd);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

I take the commands via html input, and then execute them in php via shell_exec. Everything is fine but the one I want to interact with in a specific directory that I have created in the / of the system I cannot even read the directory.

> drwxrwxr-x.   2 apache   apache 23 Aug 28 08:30 targetdir

I changed the owner of the directory and the group and the permissions and still I can't, if I run **whoami **in shell_exec, it returns the **apache** user.

So it makes me understand that it is the correct user, I don't understand it.

On the other hand, I also had to modify the file in this path:

> /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service

To modify the policy:

> PrivateTmp=false

Since I had the policy set to true, and I had problems uploading, on the other hand, my file has the following status, I'm commenting it because I don't know if it's another php service configuration problem.

```
> Description=The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
```

> After=syslog.target network.target

> [Service]
> Type=notify
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
> ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
> PrivateTmp=false
> RuntimeDirectory=php-fpm
> RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target

Thanks.

Try changing the owner and group for the target directory, to no avail.

Comment: Thankfully this does not work! Don't let users execute any command.

Comment: You should find [This Read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/php-shell-exec-permission-on-linux-ubuntu) helpful.  Not only does php/apache(www-data) need privileges .. `php` itself needs to be given access to `exec` and the shell script has to be allowed to run as the `www-data` user ..  Nevermind the OBVIOUS security flaw here ..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a high security risk and should not motivate any user doing that.

Comment: @Marcus we have no idea what OP is doing here .. He could be trying to create an experimental PHP CLI for use behind closed doors .. If that's the case security isn't a factor to OP.  Closing a question because we *think* we know what's going on, is also a slippery slope.

Comment: @Zak Here are tons of questions asked how to execute shell commands. No need for a new one with extremly high risk issue for newbies.

Comment: I have read the article, I understand the problem. Sorry, I didn't want to bother anyone, I saw that what I intend to do is not a good idea, I will look for another alternative.